Image not loading in the custom view class that extends AppCompatImageView
I have designed a custom class named PaintView. My objective is to load an image that user selects and allow the user to draw like paint brush or put different shapes on it.
Here's how I implemented the class:
package com.image.plotter

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Path
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.Log
import android.view.MotionEvent
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView

class PaintView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0
) : AppCompatImageView(context, attrs, defStyle) {
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "PaintView"
        var pathList = ArrayList<Path>()
        var colorList = ArrayList<Int>()
        var paintBrush = Paint()
        var path = Path()
    }

    init {
        paintBrush.isAntiAlias = true
        paintBrush.color = Color.BLACK
        paintBrush.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        paintBrush.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        paintBrush.strokeWidth = 8f
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if (event == null) return false

        var x = event.x
        var y = event.y

        Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent: touched at ($x, $y)")

        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                path.moveTo(x, y)
                return true
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                path.lineTo(x, y)
                pathList.add(path)
                colorList.add(Color.BLACK)
            }

            else -> return false
        }

        postInvalidate()
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDraw: drawing")
//        super.onDraw(canvas)
        for (i in pathList.indices) {
            paintBrush.color = colorList[i]
            canvas.drawPath(pathList[i], paintBrush)
            invalidate()
        }
    }
}

It mostly includes logic for free-hand drawing like paint brush.
I'm able to include PaintView in xml and even change its background colour programmatically in the Activity's code. However, when I try to load image from the drawable resource, it doesn't show any trace of the image.
Here's my xml code of MainActivity:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!--    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView-->
    <com.image.plotter.PaintView
        android:id="@+id/canvas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/image_picker_button"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/image_picker_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:text="Select image"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

And here's how I tried to load the image:
        (binding.canvas as ImageView).setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
//        binding.canvas.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
        binding.canvas.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)

The image loads properly if I use androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView instead of com.image.plotter.PaintView. What am I missing while designing com.image.plotter.PaintView?

Turns out it wasn't working because I commented out super.onDraw().
Here's what the function should look like:
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDraw: drawing")
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        for (i in pathList.indices) {
            paintBrush.color = colorList[i]
            canvas.drawPath(pathList[i], paintBrush)
            invalidate()
        }
    }

